# Please help - directory permissions going weird

Tags: permissions, directory, root, plex

I've been working on my home server for nearly 2 weeks, at the same time I'm learning Ubuntu and I got everything to a place where I want it, then today - something, went wrong..

I have three main issues, but this one is the worst:

- I've completely lost access to my primary drive:

In the below screenshot the owner is 'root' and the security is 'unknown'.

[image: As per below, the owner is 'root' and the security is 'unknown']

This drive is a ext3/ext4 file system (I don't know why or if this is good unfortunately).

The main reason I stumbled across this is because I'm desperately trying to rename my folders, but I'm getting this:

`Operation not permitted`. I've tried `/mnt/plex/media/tv`, but it doesn't work.

[image: Operation not permitted, I've tried /mnt/plex/media/tv but it doesn't work]

I feel like a complete failure. I had all my daughter's favourite movies and now she can't watch anything.

Comment: Hello, I tried that but got the following: operation not permitted.. chown: changing ownership of '/media/dandy/ae8772de-79e2-4514-8598-6e553f365043/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Simd/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Simd.dll': Operation not permitted

Comment: Have your file system checked and repaired: it looks as if it is being mounted read only.

Comment: What was the last thing you did before this happened? What is the user 1024? It appears you may have typed in bad sudo command(s); check using the `history` command.